# Java FX apps won't run on the browser with Linux

Tags: java, linux, google-chrome, firefox, javafx

This is my current system configuration:

Opensuse 12.3 x64
Nvidia Gefore 9600gt with Proprietary drivers
Tried both the Oracle Java 7u45 and 7u51 (Installed according to: SDB:Installing Java - openSUSE)
Google Chrome and Firefox (Latest versions for both)

I am not able to run any Java FX browser app. When the app starts loading, i just get a gray box inside the browser screen. I've reproduced this with the JavaFX Ensemble sample app as well as my own apps. This is the exception i get on the Java Console when trying to load the Ensemble app:

```
---- FetchDocListTask  docsUrl = http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2SwapChain.<init>(ES2SwapChain.java:79)
  at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2ResourceFactory.createPresentable(ES2ResourceFactory.java:40)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:59)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
  at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:108)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
CacheEntry[http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/Ensemble.jn     lp]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 CST 1969,length=0
CacheEntry[http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/Ensemble.jnlp]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 CST 1969,length=0
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  No solution yet.

Comment: I had to switch to Windows as i didn't had time to debug this problem but i was told this could be due to missing GTK libs.

Comment: Same problem here. If you got the solution, please inform us.

Comment: I had the exact same problem with Java 7, when using Java 8 I do not have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Chrome has actively stopped supporting Java.  This is the aftermath.  Use Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I removed pidgin and vlc.Once I added it back things worked fine.
So try that as I might not be able to  figure out the exact dependencies anytime soon

Comment: this answer is better suited to be a comment.